# Big-O Notation for a recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

This question has been asked a few times before, but I'm still having trouble finding the answer for this problem because it is more complex than the simple examples provided in the other questions.

I'm trying to find the big O notation for:

```
float foo(int start, int end, int s)
{
  if (start == end) {
    return start*start;
  } else {
    int iSegment = (end - start + 1) / s;
    int iCurrResult = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=s; i++)
      iCurrResult += foo (start + i*iSegment, start + (i+1) * iSegment - 1, s);
    return iCurrResult*iCurrResult;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time the function is called, it invokes itself recursively `s+1` times, with a range of size `n/s` (`n` is the number of elements).

This gives you the complexity function:

T(n) = (s+1)T(n/s) + 1

According to [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%20=%20%28s%2b1%29T%28n/s%29%20%2b%201), this function is in `O((s+1)^(logn/logs)) = O((s+1)^log(n-s))`

**Note** that this is in `Omega(n)`, since `n=s^log_s(n)=s^log(n)/log(s)`, and it is easy to see that this function is strictly (and asymptotically) bigger than `s^(logn/logs)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense. I have a question - how did you get the big-O of T(n) using Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: nevermind, I got that part. One more thing, why would it be O(s^(logn/logs)) instead of O((s+1)^(logn/logs)) ?

Comment: @koggiri It's a mistake, I fixed it.